# Field.Store and Field.Index both set to `NO` in a Lucene document?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I am aware of what **Field.store** and **Field.Index** means in Lucene document and aware of the use-cases when either `Field.store` or `Field.Index` is set to **NO**.

But recently, I came across piece of code, when both are set to **NO**. Could anybody explain the use-case with an example, when we need to set them to **NO** ?.

PS: I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940650/lucene-field-store-yes-versus-field-store-no) SO question, which explains why one is set to NO and another is set to Yes, with good use-cases, but it doesn't give answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene is the generic full-text indexing and search library and its not the framework in itself like ElasticSearch or Solr.

So, if you are developing your search application and directly using Lucene then you have full control over which fields to index and/or which fields to store from your app in the Lucene inverted index.

Frameworks like ElasticSearch or Solr which are built on top of Lucene, may use a schema for indexing or it might be schemaless too.

**I think in cases where it's schemaless, it makes sense to explicitly ignore the fields which we don't want to index and store both.**