# Is there a way to enable _source on existing data?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I create an Index without _source field (considerations of memory).
I want to enable this field on the existing data , there is a way to do that?

For example: 
**I will create dummy-index :**

```
PUT /dummy-index?pretty
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**and I will add the next document :**

```
PUT /dummy-index/_doc/1?pretty
{
  "name": "CoderIl"
}
```

I will get only the hit metadata when I search without the name field

```
{
   "_index" : "dummy-index",
   "_type" : "_doc",
   "_id" : "1",
   "_score" : 1.0
}
```

the question if I could change the `_soruce` to enable and when I search again I'll get the missing data (in this example "name" field) -

```
{
   "_index" : "dummy-index",
   "_type" : "_doc",
   "_id" : "1",
   "_score" : 1.0
   "_source" : {
        "name" :CoderIl"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the chat, the issue is

1. `_source` field is disabled.
2. In search result he wants what was stored in the fields which is returned as part if `_source` if enabled like below

> ```
>  _source" : {
>         "name" :CoderIl"
>    }
> ```

Now in order to achieve it, `store` option must be enabled on the field, **please note this can't be changed dynamically and you have to re-index data again with updated mapping**.

**Example**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "title" :{
                "type" : "text",
                "store" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs**

```
{
   "name" : "coderIL"
}

{
   "name" : "coderIL",
   "title" : "seconds docs"
}
```

**Search doc with fields content using [store fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#stored-fields)

```
{
    "stored_fields": [
        "title"
    ],
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": "coderIL"
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "without_source",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.18232156
            },
            {
                "_index": "without_source",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "fields": {
                    "title": [
                        "seconds docs"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

[store option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) on field controls that, from the same official doc

> By default, field values are indexed to make them searchable, but they
> are not stored. This means that the field can be queried, but the
> original field value cannot be retrieved.
>
> Usually this doesn’t matter. The field value is already part of the
> _source field, which is stored by default. If you only want to retrieve the value of a single field or of a few fields, instead of
> the whole _source, then this can be achieved with source filtering.

**As mentioned on the doc, by default its disabled, and if you want to save space, you can enable it on specific fields and need to re-index the data again**

**Edit:** [Index option](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/mapping-index.html) controls(enabled by default) whether field is indexed or not(this is required for searching on the field) and `store` option controls whether it's stored or not, this is used if you want to get the non-analyzed value ie what you sent to ES in your index request, which based on field type goes through [text analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and part of `index option`, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811011/in-what-scenario-we-need-both-field-store-and-field-index-both-set-to-no-in-a) SO question for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't enable it and I have data that I index without the source field and now I want this data (I don't sure where but it saved in ES because I can do operations on this data and get the correct awnser)

Comment: @CoderIL, I guess you are getting confused `_source` which is an index level setting(enabled by default) to `source` param which is a field specific setting(disabled by default). If you have not disabled `_source` explicitly than you are getting data from it. but to confirm this, I need to see your index mapping, your sample data and search query

Comment: I disable it (_source) explicitly - from my mapping -` \"_source\" : \{ \"enabled\" : false   }`

Comment: @CoderIL than can you show your query and what all the operations are you doing simple search? please note fields are indexed by default and refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/mapping-index.html for more info

Comment: @CoderIL added EDIT section in my answer, which should help you understand the concepts better.

Comment: Thanks, I edit my question too, maybe it make it more clear..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222514/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-coderil).