# Are there downsides of indexing every field in Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I found information about how number of shards, number of fields in mapping, affect performance of Elasticsearch. But I could not find any information about how indexing or not indexing a field affect cluster performance.

Imagine I have document like:

```
{
  "name":"John Doe", 
  "photoPath":"/var/www/public/images/i1/j/d/123456.jpg", 
  "passwordHash":"$12$3b$abc...354", 
  "bio":"..."
}
```

I need to put 10 to 100 such documents to the cluster each second. When I put such document in index I am pretty sure I'd need to fulltext search for name and fulltext search for bio. I will never search for photoPath and I will never need fulltext search for password hash.

When I do my mapping I have several options:

- make all fields text and analyze them with simple analyzer (i.e. tokenize by any not-character) - in that case I will have terms like "i1", "3b" or "123456" in my index
- make name and bio text, make password hash keyword and make photoPath non-indexed

---

So my questions are:

- In what ways, if any, am I improving performance in case I use the second option with custom tailored field types?
- Am I correct in my assumption that having less fields indexed helps performance?
- Am I correct in my assumption that indexing fewer fields will improve indexing performance?
- Am I correct in my assumption that actual search will be faster if I index only what I need?

Comment: I wholly disagree with the close vote! It does focus only on one problem. "Are there downsides of indexing every field in Elasticsearch index?". My questions in the final part could be removed, but a good answer will still need to answer all of them.

Comment: I also agree, and voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go with the answers:

1. In what ways, if any, am I improving performance in case I use the second option with custom tailored field types? --> **see detailed explanation below**
2. Am I correct in my assumption that having less fields indexed helps performance? --> **Yes**
3. Am I correct in my assumption that indexing fewer fields will improve indexing performance? --> **Yes**
4. Am I correct in my assumption that actual search will be faster if I index only what I need? --> **Most likely**

**Detailed explanation:**

Every index comes with a mapping in which you not just specify what data should get indexed but also in how many fields your data is stored and how to process the data before storing it. In its default configuration Elasticsearch will dynamically create this mapping for you based on the type of data you sent to it.

- Every single entry in your mapping consumes some bytes which will add to the size of the **cluster state** (the data structure that contains all the meta-information about your cluster such as information about nodes, indices, fields, shards, etc. and lives in RAM). For some users the cluster state simply got too big which severely affected performance. As a safety measurement Elasticsearch by default does not allow you to have more than 1000 fields in a single index.
- Depending on mapping type and optional mapping parameters Elasticsearch will create **one or more data structures for every single field you store**. There are less and more "expensive" types, e.g. keyword and boolean are rather "cheap" types, whereas "text" (for full text search) is a rather expensive type, as it also requires preprocessing (analysis) of your strings. By default Elasticsearch maps strings to a multifield made up of 2 fields: one that goes by `<fieldname>` which is of type `text` and supports full-text search, and one that goes by `<fieldname>.keyword` of type `keyword` which only supports exact match search. On top of `keyword` fields and some other field types allow you to do analytics and use them for sorting. If you don't need one or the other, then please customize your mapping by storing it only for the use case you need. It makes a huge difference if you only need to display a field (no need to create any additional data structures for that field), whether you need to be able to search in a field (requiring specific data structures like inverted indices), or whether you need to do analytics on a field or sort by that field (requiring specific data structures like doc_values). Besides the Elasticsearch fields you specify in your mapping with a type you also can control the data structures that should get created with the following mapping-parameters: `index`, `doc_values`, `enabled` (just to name a few)
- At search time it also makes a difference over how many fields you are searching and how big your index is. The **fewer fields, the smaller the index,** the better for fast search requests.

**Conclusion:**

So, your idea to customize your mapping by only storing some fields as `keyword` fields, some as `text` fields, some as multifields makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

As the question has several parts, I would try to answer them with official elasticsearch(ES) resources. Before that let's break what OP has in the ES index and every field use case:

```
{
  "name":"John Doe", //used for full text search
  "photoPath":"/var/www/pub/images/i1/j/d/123.jpg", // not used for search or retrival.
  "passwordHash":"$12$3b$abc...354", // not used for search or retrival.
  "bio":"..." //used for full text search**
}
```

Now as OP just mentioned `photoPath` and `passwordHash` aren't used for full-text search, **I am assuming that these fields will not be used even for retrieval purposes**.

So first, we need to understand what's the difference b/w indexing a field and storing the field and this is explained very well in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940650/lucene-field-store-yes-versus-field-store-no/32952682) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) article. In short, **if you have _source disabled(default is enabled), you will not be able to retrieve a field if it's not stored.**

Now coming to the optimization part and improving the performance part. **it's very simple that if you (send/store) more data what you actually need, then you wasting resources(nertwork,CPU,memory, disk)**. And ES is no different here.

Now coming to OP assumptions/questions:

1. In what ways, if any, am I improving performance in case I use the second option with custom-tailored field types? ***This option definitely better than first as you are not indexing the fields which you don't need for a search, but there is still room for optimization if you don't need to retrieve them, then it's better not to store them as well as remove from index mapping.***
2. Am I correct in my assumption that having fewer fields indexed helps performance? ***Yes, as this way your inverted index would be smaller and you would be able to cache more data from your [inverted index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-indexing-for-beginners-part3) to [file system cache](https://qbox.io/blog/authoritative-elasticsearch-search-tuning-part-3) and searching in small no of data is always faster. Apart from that, it helps to improve the [relevance of your search](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables) by not indexing the unnecessary fields for your search.***
3. Am I correct in my assumption that indexing fewer fields will improve indexing performance? ***Explained in the previous answer.***
4. Am I correct in my assumption that the actual search will be faster if I index only what I need? ***It not only improves the search speed but [improves indexing speed](https://qbox.io/blog/maximize-guide-elasticsearch-indexing-performance-part-2)(as there will be lesser segments and merging them takes less time)***

I can add a lot more information but I wanted to keep this short and simple. Let me know if anything isn't clear and would be happy to add more information.